# Riemann integral and homoemorphism

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemannian-geometry, lebesgue-measure

I am wondering what happens if I have the following setup:

I have a homeomorphism:
$\phi$ from the unit sphere to the unit cube. I know that the characteristic function of the unit sphere is Riemann integrable. Can I conclude that the characteristic function of the unit cube (result of composition) is Riemann integrable?

Answer (score 3):

Without using additional information (such as compactness), no. There is a homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$, yet only one of their characteristic functions is Riemann integrable.

Comment: But then how could I use the fact that the unit sphere has volume to conclude that the cube has volume?